# Wordpress special characters coming in ascii code

Tags: htmlspecialchars-decode

The article title on [this](http://techjuice.pk) website is 
`"Meet Youngest Art Director of Pakistan – Babrus Khan"`  The special character in the title is not encoded back when retrieved from Database and Hence I can see in Html code, the title is `"Meet Youngest Art Director of Pakistan &#8211; Babrus Khan"`

When shared on Social Media the ASCII codes appear rather than the special characters. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check the database fields, and see how it is stored.share your code

Comment: It's saved in Database as "Meet Youngest Art Director of Pakistan – Babrus Khan"